# routing problem for admin panel in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building admin panel for one web application and I've created admin folder in controllers, view, helpers folder. The problem is that I want this url (http://localhost:3000/admin/:controller/:action/:id)
to be mapped from the specified controller action id in the admin folder. By using the code bellow in routes I have to specify every controller and I can't use customs actions. Can someone help with that issue ?
My routes.rb is:

```
  namespace :admin do
         resources :products, :comments, :news
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [look it up](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments):

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :controller => /admin\/[^\/]+/
```